# How to select collection of some fields in rest service?

Tags: rest, api, wcf, odata

I call service with postman and use oData. Result is successfully listed. Service have collection type fields. I want to select some fields of collection, not all fields. Ex: "BPAddresses" is complex type, type is array. BPAddresses have "AddressName", "Street", "Block".. I want to select only one field with OData. How should I call the service using OData?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $select option in the url to fetch selected fields from Odata service, like below.

```
http://your-api-url/BPAddresses?$select=AddressName
```

[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value#using-select) to read more on OData $select option.

**Edit:**

You can also select the properties within an expanded collection. The following request expands BPAddresses and selects AddressName of BPAddresses collection.

```
http://your-api-url/yourentity?$expand=BPAddresses$&select=BPAddresses/AddressName
```

Comment: Hi,
I want select a field of collection(complex type).  AddressName is field of BPAddresses collection. BPAddresses is array. 
http://your-api-url/BPAddresses?$select=BPAddresses   ok. If i can ..$select=BPAddresses, CardCode,CardName e.g.     CardCode and CardName is not complexType, they're type edm.string.  But BPAddresses is type Collection().   How to select string with one field of collection ?

Comment: added sample url in my answer, you can visit the link in my answer for more examples.